# Using case clause in SQL

Tags: sql, select

I am struggling with the following logic in sql, let say each of my employee have a employee type such as 'E' = Employee, 'N'= Non-Employee, 'S' = Suspend. In my radio button, I have these three status and also I have an all radio button where user can show all three employee types. To show these corresponding data, I am using a store procedure. I have these code below but somehow it is not working, I manage to show 'E', 'N', and 'S' employee type, but when I choose 'A', it only show the employee type where it is `null` or `empty` in the column but what I want is to show all employee type. Below is my code: (What I want is to show all three included empty type when I selected all )

```
select  
    case when e.emp_type is null or e.emp_type = '' or @emp_type = 'A' 
    Then 'A' 
    else e.emp_type end as emp_type  
FROM t_gc_emp e  
WHERE @emp_type = e.emp_type
```

Comment: try to change where condition to this `WHERE @emp_type = e.emp_type or @emp_type = 'A'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` clause restricts the rows returned to rows with `@emp_type = e.emp_type` - in order to return all the rows when `@emp_type` is passed as `'A'` you need to add it to the condition:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN e.emp_type IS NULL OR 
                 e.emp_type = '' OR
                 @emp_type = 'A' 
            THEN 'A' 
            ELSE e.emp_type END AS emp_type  
FROM   t_gc_emp e  
WHERE  @emp_type = 'A' OR @emp_type = e.emp_type
```

Or, more elegantly, with an `in` operator:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN e.emp_type IS NULL OR 
                 e.emp_type = '' OR
                 @emp_type = 'A' 
            THEN 'A' 
            ELSE e.emp_type END AS emp_type  
FROM   t_gc_emp e  
WHERE  @emp_type IN ('A', e.emp_type)
```

Comment: Nice job, Thanks for your help.  :)

Comment: Good copy of my comment.